# Flatten an array with children using Lodash and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, lodash

Using TypeScript code, I'm trying to flatten an array of objects where each element can contain children:

```
function getMenu (menus:Array<Menu>, name:string | undefined) {
  console.log('getMenu', name, menus[0])
  const test = _(menus)
    .thru(function (coll) {
      return _.union(coll, _.map(coll, 'children') || [])
    })
  console.log('getMenu 2', test)
  return name
}
```

I have this error that is blocking me:

> argument of type 'Menu[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'List'.
>
> Index signatures are incompatible.
>
> Type 'Menu[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Menu': label, icon, route, selectable, and 2 more.

NB: The code works well in JavaScript.

Comment: For to reproduce, provide the code with stackblitz link

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/lodash-uymf4f?file=index.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_.map(coll, 'children')` returns Menu[][]. We should flatten it to make it as Menu[].

Try the below code:

```
function getMenu(menus: Array<Menu>, name: string | undefined) {
  console.log('getMenu', name, menus[0]);
  const test = _(menus).thru(function(coll) {
     const flattenData = flatten(_.map(coll, 'children')); // flattening the data here
    return _.union(coll, flattenData);
  });
  return name;
}
```

Comment: I have this error :
Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'Menu[][]'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to 'es2019' or later.

Comment: I tried it in the stackblitz link you provided. Can you update and give it to me?

Comment: I made this and it's ok :
```
function getMenu (menus:Array<Menu>, name:string | undefined) :Menu|undefined {
  return _(menus).thru(function (coll) {
    const flattenData:Array<Menu> = _.flatten(_.map(coll, 'children'))
    return _.union(coll, flattenData)
  })
    .flatten()
    .find({
      route: name
    })
}
```

Comment: @franfrLor try the updated code now. I've used lodash flatten operator to flatten it. Don't forget to Import flatten from lodash.